# Save a custom int value for each User in a .NET Web application

Tags: .net

Does .NET has any support for saving a custom int value for each (logged in) user?

Could I perhaps use the HttpContext.User property or something?

Comment: Please edit your post to explain a little more what you want.  Perhaps give an example of what you're trying to achieve and how you would want it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to look at the Session property on the HttpContext.  The HttpSession returned by that property allows storage of values (through the indexer) which are scoped on the session level.  This session is what is mapped to the individual user.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be persisted between sessions? Then you could check out the ASP.NET User Profile services - works very nicely, highly configurable.

See these articles on it:

- [Personalization and User Profiles in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163724.aspx)
- [Profiles In ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx)
- [ASP.NET 2.0 Quickstart Tutorials](http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/profile/default.aspx)

Marc